# React native: componentDidMount fails to display fetch data

Tags: react-native

Hi I am working on a programming challenge for a company where I have to develop a tinder like react native apps for pet, I am stuck in where I am not able to see any of the images, that are on a server, I am calling the correct end points in componentDidMount.I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmHywzVkKn8 and I am very new to react/react-native land, I have some experience with angualar2 where I learned to use async/await. from my limited understanding
this issue is really due to the fact that images are not rendered on time where as the view does get initialize early, I am using this to develop iOS app.

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions, Image, Animated, PanResponder} from 'react-native';


const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
export default class Pets extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
      super();
      this.position = new Animated.ValueXY()
      this.state = { 
        data: [],
        currentIndex: 0
      };

    }


    async componentDidMount(){
      const response = await fetch("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cozi-interview-dev/pets.json")
      const json = await response.json();
      this.setState({ data: json });
      }

      componentWillMount() {
        this.PanResponder = PanResponder.create({

          onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
          onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {

            this.position.setValue({ x: gestureState.dx, y: gestureState.dy })
          },
          onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {

          }
        })
      }

      renderPets = () => {

        return this.state['data'].map((item, i) => {


          if (i < this.state.currentIndex) {
            return null
          }
          else if (i == this.state.currentIndex) {

            return (
              <Animated.View
                {...this.PanResponder.panHandlers}
                key={item.id} style={[this.rotateAndTranslate, { height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 120, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, padding: 10, position: 'absolute' }]}>
                <Animated.View style={{ opacity: this.likeOpacity, transform: [{ rotate: '-30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, left: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
                  <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'green', color: 'green', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>LIKE</Text>

                </Animated.View>

                <Animated.View style={{ opacity: this.dislikeOpacity, transform: [{ rotate: '30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, right: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
                  <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red', color: 'red', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>NOPE</Text>

                </Animated.View>

                <Image
                  style={{ flex: 1, height: null, width: null, resizeMode: 'cover', borderRadius: 20 }}
                  source={item.uri} />

              </Animated.View>
            )
          }
          else {
            return (
              <Animated.View

                key={item.id} style={[{
                  opacity: this.nextCardOpacity,
                  transform: [{ scale: this.nextCardScale }],
                  height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 120, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, padding: 10, position: 'absolute'
                }]}>
                <Animated.View style={{ opacity: 0, transform: [{ rotate: '-30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, left: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
                  <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'green', color: 'green', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>LIKE</Text>

                </Animated.View>

                <Animated.View style={{ opacity: 0, transform: [{ rotate: '30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, right: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
                  <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red', color: 'red', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>NOPE</Text>

                </Animated.View>

                <Image
                  style={{ flex: 1, height: null, width: null, resizeMode: 'cover', borderRadius: 20 }}
                  source={item.uri} />

              </Animated.View>
            )
          }
        }).reverse()
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={{ height: 60 }}>

            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              {this.renderPets()}
            </View>
            <View style={{ height: 60 }}>

            </View>


          </View>

        );
      }


       }
      const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was wrong `source={item.uri}` do this `source={{uri:item.img}}`.  Edit your image source like below then the `Image` will render.

```
       <Image
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              height: null,
              width: null,
              resizeMode: 'cover',
              borderRadius: 20,
            }}
            source={{uri:item.img}} <---This is the way add image
          />
```